# WPF WrapPanel Items don't scroll one by one

Tags: wpf, xaml, wrappanel

Someone help me out, please.

I set a WrapPanel in a ListBox ItemsPanelTemplate. Also, I already set the `ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"`.

But why the listbox items are not scrolling up/down by ITEM one by one? The scroll style is still by PIXEL.

Can anyone help me?

```
<Grid>
    <ListBox x:Name="testListbox" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True">
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel Width="200" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>


        <ListBoxItem Background="LimeGreen" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="3" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True">
            <Image Height="50" Width="80" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"/>
        </ListBoxItem>

        <ListBoxItem Background="LimeGreen" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="3" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True">
            <Image Height="50" Width="80" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"/>
        </ListBoxItem>

        <ListBoxItem Background="LimeGreen" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="3" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True">
            <Image Height="50" Width="80" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"/>
        </ListBoxItem>

        <ListBoxItem Background="LimeGreen" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="3" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True">
            <Image Height="50" Width="80" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"/>
        </ListBoxItem>

        <ListBoxItem Background="LimeGreen" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="3" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True">
            <Image Height="50" Width="80" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"/>
        </ListBoxItem>

        <ListBoxItem Background="LimeGreen" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="3" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True">
            <Image Height="50" Width="80" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"/>
        </ListBoxItem>

        <ListBoxItem Background="LimeGreen" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="3" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True">
            <Image Height="50" Width="80" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"/>
        </ListBoxItem>

        <ListBoxItem Background="LimeGreen" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="3" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True">
            <Image Height="50" Width="80" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"/>
        </ListBoxItem>

        <ListBoxItem Background="LimeGreen" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="3" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True">
            <Image Height="50" Width="80" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"/>
        </ListBoxItem>

        <ListBoxItem Background="LimeGreen" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="3" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True">
            <Image Height="50" Width="80" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"/>
        </ListBoxItem>

        <ListBoxItem Background="LimeGreen" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="3" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True">
            <Image Height="50" Width="80" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"/>
        </ListBoxItem>

        <ListBoxItem Background="LimeGreen" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="3" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True">
            <Image Height="50" Width="80" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"/>
        </ListBoxItem>

        <ListBoxItem Background="LimeGreen" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="3" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True">
            <Image Height="50" Width="80" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"/>
        </ListBoxItem>

        <ListBoxItem Background="LimeGreen" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="3" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True">
            <Image Height="50" Width="80" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"/>
        </ListBoxItem>

        <ListBoxItem Background="LimeGreen" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="3" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True">
            <Image Height="50" Width="80" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"/>
        </ListBoxItem>

        <ListBoxItem Background="LimeGreen" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="3" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True">
            <Image Height="50" Width="80" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"/>
        </ListBoxItem>

    </ListBox>

</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

The wrappanel was not designed with this feature (logical scrolling) in mind.  You will need to create a new panel object deriving from the wrappanel class and then implement the IScrollInfo interface in order to achieve the results that you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I think i may be able to help, although i'm not exactly sure what you are trying to achieve. Can you be more specific; are you trying to get each ListBoxItem to have scrolling ability - for its content?

Since you can't add a ScrollViewer to the ItemPanelTemplate, have you considered adding one to the individual ListBoxItems:

Example:

```
<ListBoxItem Background="LimeGreen" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="3" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True">
                <ScrollViewer>
                    <Image Height="50" Width="80" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"/> 
                </ScrollViewer>
            </ListBoxItem>
```

For more wpf/xaml help i found this site was quite good: [www.YourCodeFactory.com](http://www.yourcodefactory.com/forum)

Comment: Thank codeB10.

I want to achieve the listbox scrolling ability that scroll image item by item. That mean I can scroll the listboxitem row by row instead of smoothly by pixel.

you can try to mark up the "<ListBox.ItemsPanel>" block in above code and try the scroll by item.

It's strange that listbox is not scrolling by item when I add the wrappanel block.

Comment: Hi - would really like to help. But i'm still not sure what you are trying to achieve.

If you want to scroll by row - a wrappanel is not necessary therefore. But if you want to populate each item with an undefined number of images, i think the setup of the listview is wrong. 

Either way, please clarify if you still require a solution. Also, not sure what you mean by smothly by pixel, what exactly are you referring to there?